# sqlite database for iphone application

Tags: iphone, ios, database, sqlite

we are developing an application for iphone,

the question:
Is the best way to run query on client (iphone) or on server?

Are there Considerations to run query on client(iphone),  such as number of data returned from query or number of queries that run on each action.

I have team always ask me to return all date from server (run query on server) and they do not want to return ids and run query at their side to get data.

ex. return full teacher name not teacher id. although the teacher table exists on client side (iphone)

so my boss ask me is this way is the best?

Comment: how do you synchronize the DB?

Comment: we have web services to make synchronize the DB, FYI, not all tables we have on iphone

Comment: the issue is not in data the issue is run query on server or in iphone?

Comment: i run the query on server because is always updated, if the data are static, maybe is faster run the query on the iphone